# How do I set GNOME 3 (fallback) icon theme to Tango?

Tags: configuration, gnome3

I tried setting it using `dconf-editor` and failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you like you could use the gnome-tweak-tool, you may find it easier in the future for changing themes in gnome3, a very handy app

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/show/361070